# How to run JAR from commandline using private JRE?

Tags: java, javafx, jar

I package and deploy my JavaFX application as a standalone application for Windows (using IntelliJ IDEA). This packages a private JRE with the deployment package.

However, for debugging purposes, I need to run the application JAR from the Windows commandline so I can see the console output.

The issue is the target computers run the 32-bit version of Java, but my application requires the 64-bit version. The JRE packaged with the application **is** the 64-bit version. But as no `java.exe` executable is included, I can not figure out how to invoke that version of the JRE from the commandline.

So the main question: **how do I launch `Application.jar` from the command line without a 64-bit version of `java.exe` on the target system?**

Is there a switch I can use for `Application.exe` that forces the console to remain open and responsive while launching the `jar` file?

Comment: just specify the full path to `java.exe`

Comment: @mrmcwolf There is no 64-bit version of `java.exe` on the target computers. The deployed package includes only `.dll` files in it's private JRE, no executables.

Comment: if you want to run the application with a specific version of `jre`, you should distribute it with it. once you provide the desired version one way or the other, just specify it when the application starts.

Comment: @mrmcwolf - Please read my question again. The correct JRE is deployed with the application. But I can not find a way to launch the JAR using that JRE. I can use the native exe provided in the package, but that will not show the console output.

Comment: the virtual machine can not be started from nowhere. or executable file is there, or it is gone. if you claim it is not what you distribute with the application is not used. of course, there is an option for the file to have a changed name, but this is specific to the tool with which you packaged the application.

Comment: According to the actual Oracle docs, the java.exe is NOT distributed with the packages generated using Package Manager. Unless they simply rename java.exe to java.dll...

Comment: what program did you use to deploy you app ?

Comment: @AhmedEmad - I updated the question. I use IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: I didn't use intillj before to deploy my app I use Launch4j I can specify bundled JRE and I can use the exe file as if it a jar for run time I can use `java -jar myApp.exe` to debug I know it's not what you want but maybe it could help as a last resort